# Outbound HTTP request from bluemix runtime

Tags: ibm-cloud

can a NodeJS application running on Bluemix make outside HTTP requests ? What address does the receiving end see ? There is a proxy that stops traffic from unknown servers on the other end, so we need to declare the origin IP. What is it for Bluemix ?

Comment: Can you consider routing your outgoing requests through a reverse proxy that isn't running on Bluemix/CloudFoundry so that you can have a consistent IP exposed to the service?

Answer (score 1):

Any application running on IBM Bluemix can make outgoing HTTP requests (or any other outgoing TCP/UDP request).

Outgoing requests will come from the IP address of the DEA running the container with this application instance. If you have multiple instances, requests can come from any of these instances.

For details on the environment variables exposing these parameters, see this page: 
http://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes a NodeJs application running on Bluemix can make outgoing requests.

The receiving end will see the IP address of the Bluemix gateway rather than the IP address of the DEA running the container. You can work out what the IP address is by doing a `nslookup` of your the app url, but the IP address(es) used is/are not currently documentation so *could* change.